# Ошибка в компиляции, связанная с Spring Data репозиторием (Не создаётся бин)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2, hql

Пишу занчит web-приложение на Spring, нужна работа с бд. В конкретном случае нужно из БД вытащить класс сущности, найденный по полю body. Вроде IDEA в коде ошибок не находит, но при запуске ошибка:

`2020-11-18 22:39:48.404  WARN 8548 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'expressionRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.web.springcalculator.repository.ExpressionRepository.findByBody(java.lang.String)!`

Код репозитория, Entity и сервиса приложен ниже.

```java
package com.web.springcalculator.repository;

import com.web.springcalculator.expressions.ExpressionEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface ExpressionRepository extends CrudRepository<ExpressionEntity, Long> {

    @Query("FROM ExpressionEntity WHERE ExpressionEntity.body = body")
    public Optional<ExpressionEntity> findByBody(String body);

}
```

```java
package com.web.springcalculator.expressions;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EXPRESSIONS")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ExpressionEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "body", nullable = false)
    @Setter
    private String body;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "answer", nullable = false)
    @Setter
    private double answer;
}
```

```java
package com.web.springcalculator;

import com.web.springcalculator.dto.ExpressionDTO;
import com.web.springcalculator.expressions.ExpressionEntity;
import com.web.springcalculator.repository.ExpressionRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExpressionService {

    private final ExpressionRepository repository;

    public Optional<ExpressionDTO> findById(final long id){
        return repository.findById(id).map(ExpressionDTO::convert);
    }
    
    public Optional<ExpressionDTO> findByBody(final String body){
        return repository.findByBody(body).map(ExpressionDTO::convert);
    }

    public void save(final ExpressionEntity entity){
        repository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не проще заменить CrudRepository на JpaRepository?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("FROM ExpressionEntity WHERE ExpressionEntity.body = ?1")
```

Comment: Не работает, ошибка та же

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM ExpressionEntity e WHERE e.body= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
```